# PowerBuilder 10 Error: "Initialization file is not writable. Cannot continue."

Tags: powerbuilder

When PowerBuilder starts up on Windows XP I receive the following error message:

> Initialization file is not writable. Cannot continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigation, it turns out the cause is that the initialisation file, PB.INI is in an area I did not have permissions to.

There are two solutions. Log in with an account with Administrator priveliges or change the location of the PB.ini file. The PB.ini file location can be changed in the registry by adding/editing the following registry key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sybase\PowerBuilder\10.0]
InitPath="NEW LOCATION of PB.INI e.g. C:\DevTools\PB10"
```

Comment: You should accept your own answer, thus the question won't be included in the "unanswered" questions

Comment: FYI, in PB version 9 the pb.ini file is located by default at C:\Program Files (x86)\Sybase\PowerBuilder 9.0